# How can I build a controlled gate for this matrix in qiskit?

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit, universal-gates

How can I build a controlled version of the below matrix in qiskit?$$
\begin{pmatrix}
e^{i\theta} &  0\\
0  &  e^{i\theta}
\end{pmatrix} = e^{i\theta}I
$$

Answer (score 2):

Simply implement the gate
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\theta} \end{array}\right)
$$
on the control qubit.